# Authorise Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-authentication, google-fit

I am using a specific `Play Service` (`Fitness`) and I am struggling with authorisation. To authorise the user I use `silentSignIn` with the proper `GoogleSignInOptions`.

```
GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, myFitSignInOptions).silentSignIn();
```

So far this works good, the user authorises my app and I can do stuff with the `Fitness API`.

The problem I have is that when I revoke access of my app from the user's account web page the `Play Services` client library still lets me use `silentSignIn` without a problem.

So my question is - is this the proper way to get user's authorisation to access their data? Is there a better or more accurate way?

Comment: Probably worth noting - I am using v15.0.0 of the Services